# Installshield patch removing registry value of the initial installation

Tags: installshield

I have installed GA and I could see the registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE-> Wow6432Node -> XXXX. After applying patch on top of that, My registry remains but the registry data (value) is removed.
Not sure what is going wrong. I have the registry entry available in my patch project. Tried to delete that and installed the patch. Even then that does not solve the issue. Any help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/StreamliningQP.htm

Has the answer. Concept of Streamline patch has resolved my issue.